# Last Resort - jQuery Mashable Mega Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have been searching for an example of how to build a mega menu like what Mashable has, but without using PHP or MySQL and I'm having a heck of time.

If anyone know, that would be great... I'm just at my wits end and my eyes are now turning square from scouring the interwebs.

I've seen several example of how to create a jQuery dropdown mega menu, where, on hover, the menu drops down the full width of the menu, and displays more options.  But I'm looking for the exact effect Mashable has, where you drop down and there is an unordered list to the left. You hover over any of those, and it reveals a sub list in the remaining area of the dropdown.

Al the example I have seen rely heavily on pulling an external php page to load in new options, but I just need it to display a sub unordered list, and not load in anything dynamically.

You can see what I'm talking about with the following link: http://mashable.com/

Can anyone help? or at least point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need any dynamic loading whats keeping you from doing it in plain HTML and CSS? You can do the transitions in CSS3 as well.

Comment: The menu would still work, but there would be no transition. Wouldn't that be ok?

Comment: i assume so, but looking for a way to get around jquery wasn't my question.